# Knowing that focus is on the left most view in Android TV

Tags: android-tv, amazon-fire-tv, d-pad

I am developing an application for Android/Fire TV.

So now my question is that -

How can I get to know that focus is on the left most view?

I have two containers: (1) a hidden left menu (similar to an Android Drawer) & (2) an area with all the content. 
In the content area there are many horizontal trays, which contain other views inside them, whenever I am at the left most view of a tray and I press LEFT on DPAD, I want to reveal the menu.

Does Android provide any method which can tell if there is/isn't a focusable item in the left when left is press on an item?